# Fetching API data with Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to fetch API data using Node JS. I am using this node package to do so.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cryptocompare

The documentation of that package is easy enough.

```
global.fetch = require('node-fetch')
const cc = require('cryptocompare')

cc.price('BTC', ['USD', 'EUR'])
.then(prices => {
  console.log(prices)
})
.catch(console.error)
```

I've tested it with [npm.runkit.com](https://npm.runkit.com/cryptocompare) and it works.

However, when I install the package into my app, I don't see any output in the console.

I am using JetBrains WebStorm and these are the steps I've taken.

1. Create New Express App
2. npm install -g express-generator
3. npm install --save node-fetch
4. npm install --save cryptocompare
5. npm install

Then within `/routes/index.js` I added the following

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
const cc = require('cryptocompare');

/* GET home page. */

cc.price('BTC', ['USD'])
    .then(prices => {
        console.log(prices)
}).catch(console.error);

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Example'
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

But that displays nothing in the console log. I tried moving the `global.fetch` to `app.js` in the root directory but that didn't do anything either.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try getting rid of the square brackets in your second example. The documentation doesn't have them.

Comment: What square brackets? the ones around `USD` ?

Comment: mmhm it's different from the example under "passing a single pair of currencies"

Comment: It's all the same, you can still pass 1 item in an array. In any case, removing the square brackets doesn't do much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
    const cc = require('cryptocompare');

    /* GET home page. */


    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
cc.price('BTC', ['USD'])
        .then(prices => {
    res.render('index', {
          title: prices
        });
    }).catch(console.error);

    });

    module.exports = router;
```

This will work for you

Comment: This returns `[object Object]` for the `title`

Comment: Fantastic. I am new to the MEAN stack. I really appreciate your patience.

Comment: @Halnex, No Problem.  if you want i can email you a book which is really nice and easy to understand. Let me know if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are not getting anything. I tried with same steps and got the result.

I just did one thing differently, i pasted whole code in a file named as **abc.js**.

and then i ran it in command line like this

node abc.js

and i got this result

> { USD: 2797.06 }

Can you please try it again because its working awesome for me. Let me know if you face any problem.

Continue...

So if you want to use it in index.js then you can do something like this

```
cc.price('BTC', ['USD'])
    .then(function(prices){
        console.log(prices)
}).catch(function(error){
console.log(error);
});
```

I just changed its syntex from es6 to es5

Comment: Yes, I just tested this and it works. But I would like to pass the data to `index.js` route instead and eventually be able to print out the data on the page instead of the console.

Comment: @Halnex Oh, wait, I assumed you were looking at your IDE's console. You are fetching the data _outside_ of the router, which means this is happening immediately as your server starts running. If you move the fetch call to inside the router and render inside the fetch callback you should see the data in your browser's console.

Comment: @spicypumpkin I've been trying to move it inside the router and render on `index.js` but the IDE keeps throwing syntax errors. I can't move the fetch snippet inside an array where the `title` is.

Comment: @Halnex What array? You should be able to access the `prices` through closure or as an object property. Can you tell me where the syntax error is? Maybe edit it into your original question and I can post a legitimate answer.

Comment: `res.render('index', { title: 'Example' });` This array. Let's say I want to print the price instead of `Example` - passing `cc.price('BTC', 'USD')` returns `[object Promise]` - I am new to the MEAN stack, I would appreciate an example.

Comment: @Halnex I guess you should read about CPS or closure concept. You will get idea how it work. Well i added a new answer. Hope that will help.